# Sending Array as a body in HTTParty post request giving : undefined method `bytesize' for #<Array

Tags: ruby, httparty, net-http

I am trying to make a post request using httparty gem.

```
    response = HTTParty.post(App.base_uri + "/api?service=post&action=update&version=2",
    body: [{"some_big_json": "with many key value pair"}],
    headers: {
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
      'Accept' => 'application/json',
      'Cookie' => @@cookie
    })
```

The Body is an array. When i make a post request, I am getting this error:

`/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:183:in send_request_with_body': undefined method bytesize' for #<Array:0x00005561f96833e0> (NoMethodError)`

How to post a large array in body using httparty?

**Update**: In the postman i am able to send body as an array and i am getting successful(expected) response.

Comment: Need more explaintion..

Comment: @adarsh
There is an api : www.example.com/api?service=post&action=update.
I need to make a post request for this api which will do some background logic and saves data.
but The request body i.e., the **payload is an array of single json object**.
When I make above request I am getting `undefined method bytesize' for #<Array`

Comment: Can you convert the array to a string before submitting?

Comment: @Mark The api returns {"result": "failed"}. if body is of string type.

Answer (score 2):

Try to pass the string rather than array.

```
response = HTTParty.post(App.base_uri + "/api?service=post&action=update&version=2",
    body: "[{'some_big_json': 'with many key value pair'}]",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
      'Accept' => 'application/json',
      'Cookie' => @@cookie
    })
```

Comment: The api returns {"result": "failed"} if body is of any other type like string.

Comment: bytesize works for the string. you need to check your api.

Comment: The api is expecting the body to be an array of json.

Comment: you can also try the RestClient::Request

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the RestClient

```
RestClient::Request.execute(method: :post,
                            url: App.base_uri + '/api',
                            payload: params,
                            timeout: 1000,
                            headers: headers)
```

Comment: response = RestClient::Request.execute(
        method: :post,
        url: App.base_uri + "/api?service=draft&action=update&version=2",
        payload: [@@req1],
        timeout: 3000,
        headers: {
         'Content-Type' => 'text/plain',
         'Accept' => 'text/plain',
         'Cookie' => @@cookie
       })
This is not working, in the api logs I am seeing request as null.
Even if i make content type as 'application/json' Its not working.

Comment: follow https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client this you will find the solution

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the array to JSON before submitting.

```
options = @options.merge(
  body: [
    {
      name: 'John Doe',
    }
  ].to_json
)
```